# Searching ID from a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to search for a student ID from a text file and display the line if an ID is found.

Here is the code:

```
sid = input ('\nPlease enter the student ID you want to search: ' )
        found = False 
        for line in student_file:
            line = line.rstrip() 
            if sid == line[0]:
                found = True
                print (line)
                print('\n')
        if found == False: 
            print ("No student record under this ID.")
```

The text file contains the student ID, name and marks of different subjects

```
1235     abc     0.0      0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0            

1111     def     19.0     20.0     30.0    20.3    12.3  

1        ghi     100.0    100.0    100.0   100.0   100.0 

5        jkl     100.0    100.0    100.0   100.0   100.0
```

Here if

- input sid = 1 then it shows the details of the students with IDs 1235,1111,1
- input is 1235, then it is displaying "no student record under this ID"
- input is 5, then it shows the student details for ID=5

All I am trying to do is display the Student record for matched Id. I don't know where am going wrong.

Comment: `line[0]` is the first **character** in the line, not the first *word*... Try looking at `line.split()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `line[0]` which is the first character you need to check the first word of line. This is because `sid` can be multiple characters.

You can do this by splitting the string at the first space and then selecting the first segment using `[0]`;

```
if (line.split(" ")[0] == sid):
```

Optionally, you could do;

```
if (sid in line.split(" ")):
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much